# Setting *.prototype methods inside angular factory not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating an angular factory that encapsulates and injectable type that can be new-ed up as such:

```
(function() {
angular
  .module('app')
  .factory('PaymentStream', [

function() {

    function PaymentStream(){

        this._endingBalance = null;
    }

    PaymentStream.prototype.serialize = function() {

        // method body here
    };

    return PaymentStream;

   }]);
})();
```

When I create a PaymentStream via `new PaymentStream()` only the constructor seems to have been called.  If I don't use `prototype` and just define the methods inside the constructor it works but then I'm redefining the functions with each instance.

Any idea why those prototypes are not being set?

***Edit***

Here is how it is being used in the outside.

```
    function addStreamFunctions(stream) {

        angular.merge(stream, new PaymentStream());
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, maybe the way you are using the factory outside is the problem? can you show how you use it from a controller or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basing on your edit, The factory was indeed working correctly. The problem is the way you used it, you `angular.merge`d the `new`ed object with another object, so its type is not a `PaymentStream` anymore, the resulting object became a 'generic' `object`

If the stream is a plain object, what you can do is pass the `stream` variable in the constructor of `PaymentStream` and do the merging manually inside your constructor function. Something like

```
function PaymentStream(stream){

    this._endingBalance = null;

    var keys = Object.keys(stream); //get all properties from the stream

    keys.forEach(function(key){
       this[key] = stream[key];   //put each one in the instance of your object;
    });

}
```

then use it like

```
function addStreamFunctions(stream) {

    var stream = new PaymentStream(stream);

}
```

this code is untested, please tell me if it worked or not :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with `factory` you need to return an instance of the object, in this case a new instance of `PaymentStream`

```
(function() {
  angular.module('my-app').factory('PaymentStream', [function() {
    function PaymentStream() {
      this._endingBalance = null;
    }

    PaymentStream.prototype.serialize = function() {
      // method body here
    };

    return new PaymentStream();
  }]);
})();
```

Comment: I think he wants the class to be returned by the factory, not an instance

Comment: @LouieAlmeda http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pad6zsvp/3/ - In that case OP's code should just work

Comment: Yes it does, I don't see anything wrong about the code either, maybe we're looking at the wrong portion of the code

Comment: @LouieAlmeda - that's exactly right, I'm looking to take the factory and use it o new up classes